# Can I skip some IPs returned by DNS round robin?

Tags: dns, ip

archive.ubuntu.com returns 4 IPs. 2 of them are much faster, the slowest one is an order of magnitude slower. Can I disallow some IPs selectively?

Comment: Host-based firewall rule to block those IPs?

Comment: Note, if you just want a local server for `apt` downloads you can of course
specify `deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt ...` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @meuh The problem is that the local mirrors are awful and give us hash sum mismatch errors weekly. So I want to avoid them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a simple local caching dns server with [dnsmasq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq), and add to the configuration file one or more lines

```
   ignore-address=<ipaddr>
```

> Ignore replies to A-record queries which include  the  specified address.   No  error  is  generated, dnsmasq simply continues to
>   listen for another reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can try placing an entry for the equivalent DNS within your `/etc/hosts` such as:

```
91.189.88.152       archive.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: I considered that but I'd rather opt out than in, in case the IPs change.

Comment: I've been burned too many times by stale leftover stuff in `hosts` to recommend putting much more than localhost in it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting IPs that are geographically far away.  Many countries have local archives. These use the two character country code as a sub-domain name. For Canada (ca), the local archives are found at ca.archives.ubuntu.com.  You may want to try using your country specific archives.  These should be closer and generally faster.

How are you determining which server is faster.  Ping times are often indicative of transfer, but not a guarantee of performance.

If you want to filter, you could build a script to dynamically update the hosts file based on measured performance.  This is only useful if `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is configured for files before DNS.